# jQuery Dialog Box not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, modal-dialog

I am having some truubles finding out, why my Jquery Dialog-box doesnt work in firefox.
In Chrome it is working fine.

```
    $(".showTasksButton").click(function() {
    return false;
    var lessonId = $(this).attr('href');
    var dialogwindow = $(this).next().clone();

    dialogwindow.dialog({
        draggable : false,
        resizable : false,
        width : 300,
        height : 350,
        zIndex : 10001,
        modal:true,
        open: function(){
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').bind('click',function(){
                dialogwindow.dialog("destroy");
            })
        },          
    })              

})
```

Does anyone of you have any ideas?

Comment: returning false in the first line of the click handler? it should not work anywhere as the dialog code is not executed at all.

Comment: What errors do you get? Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Well, to start with, you're missing a few line ending's (`;`). And as @Amareswar mentioned, you're returning false on the first line, you might've meant `event.preventDefault`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing multiple line endings and you're returning false on the first line, this code should work as intended:

```
$(".showTasksButton").click(function() {
    var lessonId = $(this).attr('href');
    var dialogwindow = $(this).next().clone();

    dialogwindow.dialog({
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 300,
        height: 350,
        zIndex: 10001,
        modal: true,
        open: function() {
            jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function() {
                dialogwindow.dialog("destroy");
            });
        },
    });
    return false;
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses.
@Amareswar: The return false comes from me, trying  if the e.preventDefault() doesnt work in firefox. So I replaced it with return false.
It turned out, that after I moved the return false to the end of these lines, it worked. 
So could it be that e.preventDefault doesnt work in firefox'
Thanks for your help

Comment: @user1576038 I updated my code, if I answered your question, please hit the checkbox to the left of my answer.